# Add category while adding product in OpenCart2.x

Tags: opencart, categories, product, opencart2.x

I'm working on a webshop using OpenCart2.x. I would like to add category while I'm adding product and assign product to that category. 
Just to clarify... Let's say I want to add "HTC One" to category "Android". I would like to go to Catalog > Product > Add Product, enter "HTC One" details and
if category "Android" dosen't exist OC should offer to create new category.
It is possible in wordpress/woocommerce so I hope it is possible in OC2.

Sorry if the question is not for this site.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is unfortunately not possible in vanilla OpenCart. However, I did find somewhat of a trick to make this process a tad bit more convenient.

If you open your OpenCart admin panel in 2 different browser instances that use different sets of cookies (different browser or incognito/no cookie mode) you can make your categories in one instance and then the category auto complete list in your product creation page will instantly update. Not exactly the desired functionality but definitely better than having to switch back and forth.

Comment: sorry but what is meant by `vanilla OpenCart`?

Comment: @Abdo Adel vanilla often refers to the default/unmodified/original version of something.

Comment: This is possible via coding :D Using vqmod :)

Comment: @Ali Zia well yes of course, but you could say that about anything. OP didn't mention mods so I am treating the answer as not needing mods